# Convergence of series with term $1/n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does WolframAlpha say that this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{a}{2}-2}}$$
converges only if $a>6$?
Shouldn't it be $a\ge 6$?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%281%2Fn%5E%28a%2F2-2%29%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: When $a=6$ you get the harmonic series, which diverges. There are [many](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf) proofs of this.

Comment: The last I heard, $\sum\frac1n$ was still divergent.

Answer (score 1):

It must be $$\frac{a}{2}-2>1$$ so $$a>6$$